# $\rm Lux$ to $\rm W/m^2$ conversion?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, units, diffraction, si-units

For a physics project, I'm planning to investigate the relationship between the number of slits in a diffraction grating and the intensity of the central maxima. The light meter which I'm planning to use to measure the intensity gives me a result in LUX.

I know the wavelength of the red laser light which I'm using is approximately $550$ nm. I'm wondering if it's at all possible to use a conversion to change the lux value in $W/m^2$?

If not, is there any other way I could possibly measure the intensity of the central maxima that would give me a result in $w/m^2$?

Comment: Could you relate this to luminous efficacy https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminous_efficacy somehow? It seems to be a part of the SI definition of lux.

Comment: (It seems to be a subjective unit, "how bright does a human think it is")

Comment: you would also need to spread your red laser over a known fixed area, and use the power rating of the laser to do the conversion

Comment: A visibly red laser definitely has another wavelength than 550nm. A He-Ne laser famously has 633 nm.

Comment: The absolute intensity doesn't matter for your purposes. Only the ratios between the peaks matter. Absolute intensity is also very hard to measure with any precision, so you are not doing yourself a favor by trying to put an absolute value on your measurements.

Answer (score 0):

This site seems to have the answer to the question and does the conversion.

https://jumk.de/calc/intensidade-luminosa.shtml

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/409556)